# Initial URI for directory on removable SD card for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: android

Audio files are being distributed for my app on a subfolder on removable SD cards. I would like to be able to direct the users to the correct folder on the SD Card, so that they can grant permission to those files, rather than them having to go looking for it.

The [Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) says to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and provide an initial URI as follows:

```
public void openDirectory(Uri uriToLoad) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
  intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriToLoad);
  startActivityForResult(intent, your-request-code);
}
```

The issue is, what to provide as the initial URL. No matter what URI I pass in the document picker **always** opens at the last folder browsed to.

I have tried multiple approaches to getting the path

- Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns **/storage/emulated/0** which is the external storage not the removable SD Card
- System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") returns null
- System.getenv("EXTERNAL_SDCARD_STORAGE") returns null
- System.getenv("ANDROID_STORAGE") returns **/storage/** which is the root of external storage and no use without the specific id for the SD Card

Calling getExternalCacheDirs and looping through the external cache directories allows me to find the full storage address of the SD Card /storage/{card-id}

I have also tried hardcoding

- /storage/{card-id}/
- content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/{card-id}
- com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/{card-id}

with the path url encoded or not

Nothing makes any difference. Document picker always opens at the last file location browsed to.

Comment: First choose the folder on the removable micro sd card.  You then know exactly how it looks like. Then use that as initial uri for next actions.

Comment: getExternalFilesDirs() will give you the id too. And there are other -better-  methods...

Comment: All of the above give valid paths - but none of them answer the question. Why does intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriToLoad) not take the user to that directory?

Comment: `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/{card-id}` looks valid. The rest cant be used.

Comment: Well please do as suggested in my first comment. Tell us the content scheme the user selected for the first time.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/{card-id)%3Adir-name is the path returned. Just realised however that %3A is : not / which could be why the urlencde is not working

Comment: `{card-id}` Dont obscure the id. Write it down like you got it. Every character.  And are you telling that with this content scheme -don't call it a path- initial uri is not working?

Comment: This is the full content scheme, as copied from Log.d content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/5307-8F4A%3Aipc
I've popped this directly into Uri.parse and it makes no difference to the opened folder (either Uri.encoded or not)

Comment: It should work. It works here. Wich Android version on used device?

Comment: Android 12. Moto G30. Will have to try on another test device when I can get my hands on one